# LinearLayout Fragment List refresh

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

This is my fragment class. Every time the "clerkship" is being changed,

i tried several methods.

1. Trigger the recreate of the entire activity. This would cause a few seconds lag due to the huge list ( 200+ items being populated for the fragment).
2. I would trigger that displayList found on this fragment from the main activity using findFragmentbyTag.
3. Delete all childView from mainActivity and add them back in.

Is there any other solution (or which of the above solution) such that i can "refresh" this list(Fragment) populated using multiple linearlayout in a quick and efficient method "instantly".

Just to add on i'm on V4 Fragment and fragments generated dynamically using PagerAdapter from main activity. Thanks so much!

```
public class EncounterFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    TextView eid;
    TextView eclerkship;
    TextView ename;
    TextView etype;
    TextView erequiredattempts;


    // DATABASE ADAPTOR
    private eAndPDbAdapter encounterDB;
    private Context myContext = getActivity();

    //arrayAdapter
    ListAdapter adapter;
    CheckBox cBox = null; 

    //Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> encountersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //various layout
    ListView encounterList;

    static String value;
    private EditText filterText = null;

    private  Cursor mCursor; 
    private Cursor cCursor; 

    String clerkShip = "null"; 



    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_ENCOUNTERS = "encounters";
    private static final String TAG_E_ID = "e_id";
    private static final String TAG_E_CLERKSHIP = "clerkship";
    private static final String TAG_E_NAME = "encounter_name";  
    private static final String TAG_E_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_E_REQUIRED_ATTEMPTS = "required_attempts";

    //JSONArray android = null;


    private List<String> nameList = new ArrayList(); 
    private List<String> idList = new ArrayList(); 
    private List<String> typeList = new ArrayList(); 
    private List<String> countList = new ArrayList(); 
    public  List encounterSelected = new ArrayList();   


    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public EncounterFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myContext = getActivity();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_encounter,
                container, false);

           encountersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            displayList();
            LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.encounterslist);


            for(int i = 0 ; i<nameList.size();i++)
            {
                View v = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.list_v, null);
                final LinearLayout single = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.listV);
                single.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LinearLayout nestedLL  = (LinearLayout) single.getChildAt(1);
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) nestedLL.getChildAt(0);
                        if(cb.isChecked())
                        {
                            cb.setChecked(false);
                            single.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cb.setChecked(true);
                            single.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 215, 0));;
                        }
                    }
                });
                TextView ID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eid);
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ename);
                TextView count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eCount);

                String nameValue = nameList.get(i).toString();
                String IDValue = idList.get(i).toString();
                String typeValue = typeList.get(i).toString(); 
            String countValue = countList.get(i).toString();

                if (typeValue.equals("Must see"))
                {
                    nameValue = nameValue + "**";
                }
                else
                {
                    nameValue = nameValue + "*";
                }

                name.setText(nameValue);
                ID.setText(IDValue);
                count.setText(" (" + countValue + ")");
                parentLayout.addView(v);
            }



        return rootView;
    }

    public void displayList()
    {
          displaySharedPreferences();

        encounterDB = new eAndPDbAdapter(myContext);
        encounterDB.open();
        mCursor = encounterDB.retrieveAllEncounterCursor(clerkShip);
        if ((mCursor != null) && (mCursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            {
            do {
                String eID = mCursor.getString(1);
                String encounter_name = mCursor.getString(3);
                String encounter_type = mCursor.getString(4);
                this.idList.add(eID);
                this.nameList.add(encounter_name);
                this.typeList.add(encounter_type);
                //change to procedure if this is procedure 
                cCursor = encounterDB.retrieveEncounterCounterBasedOnID(eID);
                int count2 =cCursor.getCount();
                if ((cCursor != null) && (count2 > 0)) {
                    cCursor.moveToFirst();
                    String NumCount = cCursor.getString(3);
                    this.countList.add(NumCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.countList.add("0");
                }

            }

            // move to the next row
            while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
        }
        encounterDB.close(); 

    }



public void displaySharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext);

    String listPrefs = prefs.getString("listpref", "No Clerkship Selected");

    StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
    builder2.append(listPrefs);
clerkShip = builder2.toString();
}   
}
```

Comment: yes, there is the way, it is commonly used and we used to call it ListView ... i'm ListView + CursorAdapter (+ ContentProvider) and i don't have problems even with 40K rows or more ...

Comment: memory leaks, recycle of ID, wtf? first i see the problem in your loop you never close `cCursor` and you are creating it for every row in `mCursor` ... checkboxes with Adapters should be used in the different way ... on check you should store the id of item(not view) in some sparsearray of ids the on getView you should check if item at position id is once from this array and eventualy check the checkbox for this row(because of ListView is reusing the views)